# What is the most elegant way to convert a hyphen separated word (e.g. "do-some-stuff") to the lower camel-case variation (e.g. "doSomeStuff")?

Tags: java

What is the most elegant way to convert a hyphen separated word (e.g. "do-some-stuff") to the lower camel-case variation (e.g. "doSomeStuff") in Java?

Comment: WTH is every example answer implemented a public static method?  When this should clearly be an hidden implementation detail of a larger abstraction.

Answer (score 99, accepted):

Use [`CaseFormat`](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/base/CaseFormat.html) from [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/):

```
import static com.google.common.base.CaseFormat.*;

String result = LOWER_HYPHEN.to(LOWER_CAMEL, "do-some-stuff");
```

Comment: which one is LOWER_HYPHEN? "do-some-stuff" or "do_some_stuff"?

Comment: [A hypen is `-`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyphen). Therefore [`LOWER_HYPEN` is "do-some-stuff"](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/base/CaseFormat.html#LOWER_HYPHEN). ["do_some_stuff" would be `LOWER_UNDERSCORE`](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/base/CaseFormat.html#LOWER_UNDERSCORE).

Answer (score 20):

With Java **8** there is finally a *one-liner*:

```
Arrays.stream(name.split("\\-"))
    .map(s -> Character.toUpperCase(s.charAt(0)) + s.substring(1).toLowerCase())
    .collect(Collectors.joining());
```

Though it takes splitting over 3 *actual* lines to be legible ツ

(Note: `"\\-"` is for kebab-case as per question, for snake_case simply change to `"_"`)

Comment: Replacing the `map` with `.map(s -> new StringBuilder().append(s.charAt(0)).append(s.substring(1)))` _might_ be more optimal

Comment: but that solution lacks a `toUpperCase()`. So I guess what you mean is : `.map(s -> Character.toUpperCase(s.charAt(0)) + s.substring(1))`. Also as far as I know, the JVM automatically replaces simple text concattenations by stringbuilder instances when necessary these days. (only do that if you have more complicated structures, e.g. conditional concats). Having said that: Thanks a lot for your answer. Helped me out today !

Comment: @bvdb ahem my previous comment is utter nonsense... aside: answer edited to improve.  Should have know better than to 2nd guess Java optimization; [JEP 280: Indify String Concatenation](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/280)

Comment: You don't need to escape the `-` because it isn't a special character in itself.

Answer (score 10):

The following method should handle the task quite efficient in O(n). We just iterate over the characters of the xml method name, skip any '-' and capitalize chars if needed.

```
public static String toJavaMethodName(String xmlmethodName) { 
  StringBuilder nameBuilder = new StringBuilder(xmlmethodName.length());    
  boolean capitalizeNextChar = false;

  for (char c:xmlMethodName.toCharArray()) {
    if (c == '-') {
      capitalizeNextChar = true;
      continue;
    }
    if (capitalizeNextChar) {
      nameBuilder.append(Character.toUpperCase(c));
    } else {
      nameBuilder.append(c);
    }
    capitalizeNextChar = false;
  }
  return nameBuilder.toString();
}
```

Comment: Why the char array, when you can just use charAt()?

Comment: @Thorbjörn - I just prefer the enhanced for loop expression. Personal style. But you right - not using 'toCharArray()' should be slightly faster

Answer (score 8):

Why not try this:

1. split on "-"
2. uppercase each word, skipping the first
3. join

**EDIT**: On second thoughts... While trying to implement this, I found out there is no simple way to join a list of strings in Java. Unless you use `StringUtil` from apache. So you will need to create a `StringBuilder` anyway and thus the algorithm is going to get a little ugly :(

**CODE**: Here is a sample of the above mentioned aproach. Could someone with a Java compiler (sorry, don't have one handy) test this? And benchmark it with other versions found here?

```
public static String toJavaMethodNameWithSplits(String xmlMethodName)
{
    String[] words = xmlMethodName.split("-"); // split on "-"
    StringBuilder nameBuilder = new StringBuilder(xmlMethodName.length());
    nameBuilder.append(words[0]);
    for (int i = 1; i < words.length; i++) // skip first
    {
        nameBuilder.append(words[i].substring(0, 1).toUpperCase());
        nameBuilder.append(words[i].substring(1));
    }
    return nameBuilder.toString(); // join
}
```

Comment: This creates a lot of String objects (~ 8 extra Strings + one array  for the given example). This could be a problem if you have to process a lot of xml tags.

Comment: The JVM is very well equipped for handling a lot of short lived objects, including Strings.

Comment: Hmm.. i think there are some solutions performing better.

Comment: The OP wanted this done in a "neatful" way. I find working like this keeps the intent of code clear. But go ahead. Optimize. Then, let us compare the two approaches. The StringBuilder approach might even be slower, since we only have very few strings here and joining an array of strings should be a O(n) operation.

Answer (score 6):

If you don't like to depend on a library you can use a combination of a regex and `String.format`. Use a regex to extract the starting characters after the `-`. Use these as input for `String.format`. A bit tricky, but works without a (explizit) loop ;).

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(convert("do-some-stuff"));
    }

    private static String convert(String input) {
        return String.format(input.replaceAll("\\-(.)", "%S"), input.replaceAll("[^-]*-(.)[^-]*", "$1-").split("-"));
    }

}
```

Comment: Could you expand on how the second replace all expression "[^-]*-(.)[^-]*" works?

Answer (score 5):

For those who has com.fasterxml.jackson library in the project and don't want to add guava you can use the jaskson namingStrategy method:

```
new PropertyNamingStrategy.SnakeCaseStrategy.translate(String);
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is a slight variation of [Andreas' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3618733/how-to-convert-do-some-stuff-to-lower-camelcase-dosomestuff-in-the-most-neatf/3618789#3618789) that does more than the OP asked for:

```
public static String toJavaMethodName(final String nonJavaMethodName){
    final StringBuilder nameBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    boolean capitalizeNextChar = false;
    boolean first = true;

    for(int i = 0; i < nonJavaMethodName.length(); i++){
        final char c = nonJavaMethodName.charAt(i);
        if(!Character.isLetterOrDigit(c)){
            if(!first){
                capitalizeNextChar = true;
            }
        } else{
            nameBuilder.append(capitalizeNextChar
                ? Character.toUpperCase(c)
                : Character.toLowerCase(c));
            capitalizeNextChar = false;
            first = false;
        }
    }
    return nameBuilder.toString();
}
```

It handles a few special cases:

- `fUnnY-cASe` is converted to `funnyCase`
- `--dash-before-and--after-` is converted to `dashBeforeAndAfter`
- `some.other$funky:chars?` is converted to `someOtherFunkyChars`

Answer (score 2):

get The Apache commons jar for StringUtils. Then you can use the capitalize method

```
import org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils;
public class MyClass{

    public String myMethod(String str) {
        StringBuffer buff = new StringBuffer();

        String[] tokens = str.split("-");
        for (String i : tokens) {
            buff.append(StringUtils.capitalize(i));
        }

        return buff.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: I had no choice to import other libraries but Apache Commons is a common factor for all project. I wish this answer also gets most number of votes :)

Answer (score 2):

As I'm not a big fan of adding a library just for one method, I implemented my own solution (from camel case to snake case):

```
public String toSnakeCase(String name) {
    StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();
    for(int i = 0; i < name.length(); i++) {
        if(Character.isUpperCase(name.charAt(i))) {
            if(i > 0) {
                buffer.append('_');
            }
            buffer.append(Character.toLowerCase(name.charAt(i)));
        } else {
            buffer.append(name.charAt(i));
        }
    }
    return buffer.toString();
}
```

Needs to be adapted depending of the in / out cases.

Comment: Still usefull to me, even if it is the reverse of the asked question. :)

Answer (score 0):

In case you use Spring Framework, you can use provided StringUtils.

```
import org.springframework.util.StringUtils;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class NormalizeUtils {

    private static final String DELIMITER = "_";    

    private NormalizeUtils() {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Do not init.");
    }

    /**
     * Take name like SOME_SNAKE_ALL and convert it to someSnakeAll
     */
    public static String fromSnakeToCamel(final String name) {
        if (StringUtils.isEmpty(name)) {
            return "";
        }

        final String allCapitalized = Arrays.stream(name.split(DELIMITER))
                .filter(c -> !StringUtils.isEmpty(c))
                .map(StringUtils::capitalize)
                .collect(Collectors.joining());

        return StringUtils.uncapitalize(allCapitalized);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Iterate through the string. When you find a hypen, remove it, and capitalise the next letter.