# Convert sentence to variable name syntax

Tags: java

How would I convert a String from something like "Bobs big barbeque" to bobsBigBarbeque?

```
String variableName = result;
for ( int i = 0; i < result.length( ); i++ ) {
    char c = result.charAt( i );
    if ( c == ' ' ) {
       Character.toUpperCase( variableName.charAt( result.indexOf( c )+1 ) );
    }
    variableName = variableName.replace( " ", "" );
    Character.toLowerCase( variableName.charAt( 0 ) );
    System.out.println( variableName );
}
```

I almost have it working. My only problem now is with the line....

```
Character.toLowerCase( variableName.charAt( 0 ) );
```

I have to just convert the first character to lowercase

Comment: Got any code to show?

Comment: It is called camel-case. Take a look at it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3618733/how-to-convert-do-some-stuff-to-lower-camel-case-dosomestuff-in-the-most-nea

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
String str = "Bobs big barbeque";
str = str.replace(" ", "");
```

If you only want to replace space from given string try above code:

I wrote code below based on your given input and output:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String str = "Bobs big barbeque";
    String newStr = String.valueOf(str.charAt(0)).toLowerCase();
    for (int i = 1; i < str.length(); i++) {
        if (str.charAt(i) == ' ') {
            newStr = newStr
                    + String.valueOf(str.charAt(i + 1)).toUpperCase();
            i = i + 1;
        }
        newStr = newStr + String.valueOf(str.charAt(i));
    }

    System.out.println(newStr);
}
```

Comment: replaceAll would be better

Answer (score 1):

```
String sentence = "Bobs big barbeque";
String[] words = sentence.split(" ");
String newVarName = "";

for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
  if (i == 0) {
    newVarName += words[i].toLowerCase();
  } else {
    newVarName += words[i].substring(0,1).toUpperCase() + words[i].substring(1);
  }
}
```

You'll probably want to take the time to make it more secure by making sure the substrings don't overflow but essentially it takes your sentence, breaks it apart on spaces then reconstructs it by making the first word lowercase and all others start with a capital.

EDIT: Fixed my string function names... alternatively you could do this which I think looks cleaner:

```
for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
    newVarName += words[i].substring(0,1).toUpperCase() + words[i].substring(1);
}
newVarName = newVarName.substring(0,1).toLowerCase() + newVarName.substring(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String a = "Bobs big barbeque";
a = WordUtils.capitalizeFully(a);  //Capitalize the first letter of each word only 
a = a.replace(" ", "");            // Remove Spaces
a = a.substring(0,1).toLowerCase() + a.substring(1); // Lowercase first letter
```

Note: or just capitalize(a) to capitalize the first letter of each word, and leave the rest of the word alone. E.g.

BoBs bIg barBeque would be BoBs BIg BarBeque with capitalize(a)

Bobs Big Barbeque with capitlizeFully(a);

Answer (score -1):

```
String a = "Bobs big barbeque";
String r = a.replace(" ","");
```

r now contains your string without spaces...

Comment: question says its output should be "bobsBigBarbeque"

Comment: My bad, didn't see it. On the other side the question wasn't much detailed...