# JSON to Xml - Hyphenated element name conversion

Tags: java, json, xml

in an XML file that uses hyphenated names for XML element Names - i need to convert the xml to JSON so that our webservice project(resteasy) understands the json. i have 1000s of these xml files - i need to find a quick way to automate these conversions.

what library can i use to accomplish this - i tried suggestions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1823264/81367) but it didnot help

any suggestions?

**example:**

**input:**

```
<card-transaction xmlns="http://ws.google.com">
      <card-transaction-type>${card-transaction-type}</card-transaction-type>
      <merchant-transaction-id>${merchant-transaction-id}</merchant-transaction-id> 
</card-transaction>
```

Output:

```
{
    "merchantTransactionId": "${merchantTransactionId}",
    "cardTransactionType": "${cardTransactionType}"
}
```

Comment: I think this answer may be useful : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3618733/how-to-convert-do-some-stuff-to-lower-camel-case-dosomestuff-in-the-most-nea

Comment: Sadly, questions on StackOverflow that ask for help finding a library tend to get short shrift from the moderators. SO users are not expected to use libraries, you're expected to write the code yourself (-;

Comment: @PeterTillemans :i will try those suggestions!

Answer (score 1):

One approach (there are many others): XSLT 3.0 defines an XML vocabulary that's essentially a direct representation of the JSON you want to generate. Use XSLT to convert the XML into that vocabulary, then press the button (more literally, invoke the `xml-to-json()` function).

http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#json