# Java Replace All : how to change every letter after an underscore?

Tags: java, regex, replaceall

I'd like to change every word using an underscore as word without underscore but with an uppercase

Example : new_york -> newYork

so far my solution is writing a line for every letter, which is not very efficient:

```
mySolution = mySolution.replaceAll("_a", "A");
```

Edit: This question is all about using ReplaceAll in one line and has therefore nothing to do with the other question. I can manage writing a "long" program but I guess most users would be happy to get an actual answer to that question.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3618733.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew actually closing as duplicate, the target question provides both native and 3rd-party solutions applicable.

Comment: You just need to use a regex with a match in `replaceAll()` like this `mySolution.replaceAll("_([a-zA-Z]{1})", "$1");`.

Comment: I tried but it only removes the underscore.

Comment: It's not possible doing it in one expression and you didn't say anything about that before the edit. Btw. no reason to do it in one line - write a method.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class HelloWorld {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(convert("Hello W_o_rld_"));
    }

    static String convert(String s) {
        StringBuilder sc = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length() - 1; i++) { //to avoid _ at last index
            if (s.charAt(i) == '_') {
                sc.append((Character.toUpperCase(s.charAt(i + 1))));
                i++;

            } else {
                sc.append(s.charAt(i));
            }
        }
        return sc.toString();
    }
}
```

Iterate through the chars of String and modify the next char after _

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: @JuanCarlosMendoza Did that

Comment: The answer as is will skip the last character of the target `String`, and not work with consecutive underscores (amongst others).

Comment: @Mena I see that question is marked as Dup, after my answer, but skipping last char is with a purpose (already explained in comment) and it takes care of consecutive underscores too